# How to convert from grams to lbs in C#

Tags: c#, unit-conversion

My question is how do I convert from kg to pound and oz?

I know that 1kg=1000gm and 2 lb 3.274 oz (1 lb = 16 oz)

I will read a file containing:

> weight 3000 gm for A and for B the  weight is 90 kg

So the result for 3000 kg will be **weight 188 lb and 1.6 oz**.

```
static void ToLB(double Weight, string type)
{
    double Weightgram, kgtopounds;
    // lbs / 2.2 = kilograms
    // kg x  2.2 = pounds

    if (type == "g")
    {
        // convert gram to kg
        Weightgram = Weight * 1000;
        // then convert kg to lb
        kgtopounds = 2.204627 * Weight;
        //convert gram to oz" 

        Weightgram = Weightgram * 0.035274;
        Console.Write("\n");
        Console.Write(kgtopounds);
    }
// I want to convert each gram and kg to pounds and oz using C#
```

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure exactly what you're asking here. Are you asking how to get ounces from a decimal value of pounds, or something else?

Comment: i want to convert kg to lb and oz for example 3000 g will be after conversion 188 lb and 1.6 ....we use RE in C# to get the weight in kg then convert it to lb and oz

Comment: I'm still confused - neither of 3000g, 300g, 300kg, or 3000kg will give you 188 lb and 1.6 oz.

Comment: Just base them all to something common and it's trivial, this isn't really a programming question?

Comment: double WeightPounds = Weight/1000/2.204627
if weight is in grams, you will need to divide by 1000 to get the weight in kilograms, then you can divide by the 2.204627 to get the number of pounds.
Any conversion for any unit of measure can be ready like the following:
 1000g/1kg = 1000 grams per kilogram
or
 1kg/1000g = 1 kilogram per 1000 grams
Finally, once you have your number (which is presumably 12.3456), take the numbers before the decimal point (number of pounds), as for number after the decimal point, this is a percentage of one, so just take it times 16 (number of ounces in a pound)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should instead use an `enum` for your type (that is, if it fits your model of reading the file and whatnot). Here's the solution I derived:

```
public static void ConvertToPounds(double weight, WeightType type)
{
    switch (type)
    {
        case WeightType.Kilograms:
        {
            double pounds = weight * 2.20462d;
            double ounces = pounds - Math.Floor(pounds);
            pounds -= ounces;
            ounces *= 16;
            Console.WriteLine("{0} lbs and {1} oz.", pounds, ounces);
            break;
        }
        default:
            throw new Exception("Weight type not supported");
    }
}
```

[ideone link](http://ideone.com/lyO4rC)

Comment: Note: the used factor is very inaccurate for converting grams to pounds. Use `weight / 453.59237` instead.